# FromBase64String results in invalid length

Tags: c#, serialization, base64, deserialization

I'm running into an issue with serializing / deserializing using the `Convert.ToBase64String` and `FromBase64String`.

My code will currently take a class, serialize to memory stream, then convert the memory stream into a string using `ToBase64String(`.

When I try to deserialize, the first thing I'm doing is `FromBase64String()`.

Upon running the `FromBase64String()`, though, it will sometimes throw an error stating that the string is an invalid length.

Would anyone be able to provide clarity as to why it's not properly converting to base 64?

Edit:

Thanks everyone. I was able to figure out what the issue was: I was forgetting to clear the memorystream before serializing more data.

Comment: Could you provide an exampe of such string which will throw the error?

Comment: And what happens between serializing and deserializing with the the serialized string?

Comment: I don't have the code in front of me, at the moment, to provide a string example. In between serializing and deserializing is where the string conversions happen. The class is serialized to memory stream, via BinaryFormatter. From there, the stream (bytes [])  is converted to / from a string.

Comment: We need to see your actual code in order to fix it.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll report back with the code in a few hours once I get back to my desk.